# Compact Framework 3.5 image Gradient not smooth

Tags: image, compact-framework, render, gradient

Why doesn't compact framework 3.5 render Images with gradient right on windows mobile?

Comment: If your image contained originally 32 bits of color and your device LCD only supports 16 bits (which is usually the case) then you will see some degradation on the image quality while displaying it.

Comment: It does not appear as an answer but, as Comment, rewrite as aswer please so I can tick it as completed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your image contained originally 32 bits or 24 bits of color and your device LCD only supports 16 bits (which is usually the case) then you will see some degradation on the image quality while displaying it.

Comment: I would have voted for the right answer. But if I do the gradient by code it looks normal and smooth, not broken.

Comment: could you give more details on how you are loading the image when it does not show smooth?